# Cannot install WordPress Plugins in dashboard on Bitnami Apache (Amazon Lightsail)

Tags: wordpress, apache, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

I'm trying Amazon Lightsail for first time and using Bitnami WordPress package for Apache.

It's been extremely frustrating as they've locked-down everything and made it all complicated: vhosts, .htaccess, FTP, directory permissions, used symlinks for no reasonable reason.

What I need to change:

I want to be able to install/delete plugins from WP Admin dashboard, and I can't get it working. Trying to delete a plugin and it asks for FTP permissions (which I can't use because Lightsail only let me do SFTP using ssh key, not supported in WP).

So something supposed to take 3 minutes has taken me 5 hours to figure out.

I already **chmod**'ed/**chown**'ed all the directories in `/wp-content` to 775 and www-data:www-data, but still won't let me delete a plugin I deactivated, keeps asking for FTP credentials.

What do I need to do to make this work?

Also, I want WordPress to be able to update itself and plugins automatically. But cannot do this currently either.

I'm thinking of just deleting all the files on Bitnami, and installing WordPress without all these restrictive permissions on folders/files and without the annoying symlinks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. The user must be set to `bitnami:daemon` for `/bitnami/wordpress/wp-content` and all child folders and files.